# having an order with multiple requests

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

i want to do a autoshop software... where they keep up the cars they have and what they need(engine and other parts for example) but i dont know how to do the database to accept multiple items at once

example:
a car needs on one visit to the auto shop:

left frontal door
tires
oil change
filters

how to i add this in one go to the database(with prices included) so that i can see it all after and print a bill wheer it shows all... but my main priority is being able to insert all in one go and in one table

Comment: Can you provide a draft of your database schema so that we can help you to improve it?

Comment: thats the thing joel... i have no idea hot to do the database good enough to do that... what i have is

table car
ID_carro Int (car)
ID_marca  Int (model)
Ano int (year)
ID_combustivel(type of fuel)


table car parts
ID_peça int (car part)
Peça  varchar(50)

and now i dont know how to do a table to insert the brand and model of the car and join all the parts it needs with individual prices and total price in one table. can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without any idea about your db strucutre. Lets assume db isn't constructed yet, you don't want to decrease parts stock or keep any track of wich exact part (i mean with serial etc.) was used. You want it quite simple, just a table with a car bought some parts.

In this case i woulde use a table looking like this : id|date|car_id|parts_used
where parts_used is a string containing parts and prices with separators. For example : "left frontal door=500+tires=100+oil=10" and then split the string when reading db.

I'm not sure it's what you want but your question isn't quite precise :)

Comment: yes it is... how do i separate the string to read it one item at a time so i can see it after if needed

Comment: and what is the code to join all parts needed and insert them on the collumn like u showed there.... ty

Comment: Which language do you use ?

Comment: vb.net and sql express 2012

Comment: i still dont know how i can insert multiple IDs into a single column... being the IDs the car parts IDs

Comment: for example: 
        `Dim s As String = "first-second-third"`
        `Dim parts As String()`
        `parts = s.Split("-")`
This will give you an array of three strings containing "first" "second" and "third"
To join, just concat strings (s = s1 & s2 & s3 and so on)

Comment: Sorry, i realized you posted while i did too. So if your car and parts tables already exists as dicribed above, the answer to your question is : that's not possible. You have to create another table (corresponding to a relation on the MCD). If all off this sounds "fuzzy" to you, you should spend time on merise tutorials. db conception isn't trivial at all.